# How do I get several highest values from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like

```
id  f1
--------------
1   2000-01-01
1   2001-01-01
1   2002-01-01
1   2003-01-01
```

And I want to get say the latest 3 dates in one row

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  f1 DATETIME NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Test (id, f1) VALUES (1, '1/1/2000')
INSERT INTO Test (id, f1) VALUES (1, '1/1/2001')
INSERT INTO Test (id, f1) VALUES (1, '1/1/2002')
INSERT INTO Test (id, f1) VALUES (1, '1/1/2003')

SELECT T1.* FROM Test as T1
```

Was trying something like

```
         SELECT T1.*,T2.* 
           FROM Test AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id AND (T2.f1 > T1.f1)
```

Comment: Why does it have to be all in one row? It would be much easier to have only one column.

Comment: I think it makes much more sense to return them as rows, and not 1 row with multiple columns.

Comment: do you need the three latest date for each id? (I noticed that your id is always 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql server you could do `select top 3 * from Test order by f1 desc`. Other DBMS's have similar posibilities such as MySql's `limit`, Oracle's `rownum` etc.

Comment: This wouldn't work. This would give the latest 3 dates in one column. Maestro1024 is asking for latest 3 dates in one row.

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm not sure how to get them into a single row, you could start with:

```
SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY f1 DESC LIMIT 3
```

That should give you a result like:

```
id  f1
1   2003-01-01
1   2002-01-01
1   2001-01-01
```

Putting them into a single row, though, may be a bit more difficult...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a combination of `ORDER BY`, `TOP` and `PIVOT`, at least on SQL Server. It seems that many of the other answers have ignored the need for the result to be "all on one row."

Answer (score 2):

in T-SQL (This will get you the top three dates even if they are all the same value)

```
with TestWithRowNums(f1, row_num) as
(
select f1, row_number() over(order by [f1] desc) as row_num from test
)
select
(select [f1] from TestWithRowNums where row_num = 1) as [Day 1],
(select [f1] from TestWithRowNums where row_num = 2) as [Day 2],
(select [f1] from TestWithRowNums where row_num = 3) as [Day 3]
```

This will get you the top three DISTINCT dates

```
with TestWithRankNums(f1, rank_num) as
(
select f1, dense_rank() over(order by [f1] desc) as rank_num from test
)
select
(select top 1 [f1] from TestWithRankNums where rank_num = 1) as [Day 1],
(select top 1 [f1] from TestWithRankNums where rank_num = 2) as [Day 2],
(select top 1 [f1] from TestWithRankNums where rank_num = 3) as [Day 3]
```

Try this in SQL Server 2005

```
--to get top three values even if they are the same
select [1] as Day1, [2] as Day2, [3] as Day3 from 
(select top 3 f1, row_number() over(order by [f1] desc) as row_num from test) src
pivot
(
max(f1) for row_num in([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt
--to get top three distinct values
select [1] as Day1, [2] as Day2, [3] as Day3 from 
(select f1, dense_rank() over(order by [f1] desc) as row_num from test) src
pivot
(
max(f1) for row_num in([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL and this is not working. Is the syntax correct or just not valid on MS SQL?

Comment: @Maestro1024, this would only work on new versions of SQl Server, but it certainly passes the syntax check.

Comment: @Maestro1024, what version of MS SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called pivot table, here is an article on how to do it:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740

also, if you use Oracle I would look at analytic functions, OVER PARTITION BY in particular

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
SELECT T1.f1 as "date 1", T2.f1 as "date 2", T3.f1 as "date 3"
  FROM (SELECT *
         FROM `date_test`
        ORDER BY `f1` DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS T1,
      (SELECT *
         FROM `date_test`
        ORDER BY `f1` DESC
        LIMIT 1, 1) AS T2,
      (SELECT *
         FROM `date_test`
        ORDER BY `f1` DESC
        LIMIT 2, 1) AS T3
;
```

Which outputs :

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| date 1     | date 2     | date 3     |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2003-01-01 | 2002-01-01 | 2001-01-01 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

The only downside is that you need at least three rows, otherwise it won't return anything...

Using `JOIN`, you can do this :

```
SELECT T1.id, 
       T1.f1 as "date 1", 
       T2.f1 as "date 2", 
       T3.f1 as "date 3"
  FROM `date_test` as T1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `date_test` ORDER BY `f1` DESC) as T2 ON (T1.id=T2.id AND T1.f1 != T2.f1)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `date_test` ORDER BY `f1` DESC) as T3 ON (T1.id=T3.id AND T2.f1 != T3.f1 AND T1.f1 != T3.f1)
 GROUP BY T1.id
 ORDER BY T1.id ASC, T1.f1 DESC
```

Which will return something like :

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | date 1     | date 2     | date 3     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2001-01-01 | 2003-01-01 | 2002-01-01 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

The downside is that `date1`, `date 2` and `date 3` will not necessarily be in a specific order (as per the above sample output). But this can be achieved programatically. The plus side is that you can insert a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY` and you can search by `T1.id`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get top 3 dates in a row by pivoting the table and perhaps concatenating the dates if you want them in one column after pivoting.

Edit :
here is a query to pivot the table and provide the latest 3 dates in a row. But to pivot you would need to know the data that is available in the table. I figured since we are querying for the latest 3 dates we will not know the exact vales to pivot around the date column. So First, I queried the latest 3 dates into a temp table. Then ran a pivot on the row_number 1, 2 and 3 to obtain the latest 3 dates in a row.

```
Select Top 3 * into #Temp from Test order by f1 desc
```

Now, pivot on the row_number column -

```
SELECT id,[3] as Latest,[2] as LatestMinus1,[1] as LatestMinus2
FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f1) AS RowId,f1,id from #Temp) AS Src
PIVOT (Max(f1) FOR RowId IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS pvt
```

This results in -

```
Id | Latest                  |LatestMinus1             |LatestMinus2
1  | 2003-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

And, of course

```
drop table #Temp
```

Comment: Edit : Added a query to my answer.

Comment: Analytics aren't supported by all databases - SQL Server 2005+, Oracle 9i+, PostgreSQL 8.4+... but not MySQL